# CCSM: Composite refresh rate reset when i reboot

Tags: compiz, ccsm

When i use `compizconfig-settings-manager` (ccsm) I want the compositor refresh rate at `144` but it doesn't stay saved it returns at `50` every-time I restart plz help me to make it stay at `144` at reboot.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
1920x1080     60.00 + 144.00*  119.98    99.93    84.90  
1680x1050     59.95  
1440x900      59.89  
1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
1280x960      60.00  
1280x800      59.81  
1280x720      60.00  
1152x864      75.00  
1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
640x480       75.00    59.94  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: show output of : `xrandr -q`

Comment: Did you turn off the Detect Refresh Rate option?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**:

Generate `modeline`:
Type `cvt 1920 1080 144` then copy generated line (start from **Modeline**).

Make your configuration file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` e.g `monitor.conf` like this :

> ```
> Section "Device"  
>   Identifier    "Configured Video Device"  
> EndSection
>
> Section "Monitor"
>   Identifier    "Configured Monitor"  
>   paste your copied modeline here eg. : 
>   Modeline "1920x1080_144.00"  452.50  1920 2088 2296 2672  1080 1083 1088 1177 -hsync +vsync
> EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>   Identifier    "Default Screen"
>   Monitor       "Configured Monitor"
>   Device        "Configured Video Device"
>    SubSection "Display"
>     Modes     "1920x1080_144.00"
>    EndSubSection
> EndSection
> ```

**Solution 2**:

You can make in your home folder `.xprofile` file and paste:

> `xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144`

This will be applied after login to your profile.